# Oracle12c, JDBC, identity and getGeneratedKeys

Tags: jdbc, oracle12c

I'm trying to do something that works in every DB I have worked with.  I want to get the generated keys from an insert.  I have oracle 12c setup and have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE countyUsers (id integer GENERATED AS IDENTITY,first varchar(255),last varchar(255),email varchar(255),userName varchar(255),unisonFailedLogins number,unisonLastFailedLogin number,unisonLastSuccessLogin number);
```

Then I run an insert and try to get a generated key using the jdbc thin driver:

```
ps.executeUpdate();
ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
if (rs.next()) {
  long id = rs.getLong(1);
}
```

which throws a number format exception.  I can get a rowid though.  The key coming back is `AAAWyHAAGAAAAFNAAA` not a number.  What am I supposed to do with this?

Thanks

Comment: Check out the doc at https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/jdbcvers.htm#JJDBC28099

Comment: thanks but that doesn't really help as it has "..." after getting the rowid and doesn't show how to use it

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, solution was to tell Oracle which column to return:

```java
String[] generatedKeyColumns = new String[]{"id"};
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(insertStatement, generatedKeyColumns);
```

Comment: you deserve a statue man!